# Programming approach theory. When to write single-purpose functions?

Tags: php, coding-style, theory, code-organization

I am very sorry, but I am unable to define this "thing" that I'm trying to figure out.

When writing functions we can take different approaches, I have made some "placeholder" examples:

```
--------A---------
getImageSmall();
getImageLarge();
getTextSmall();
getTextLarge();
--------B---------
getImage('small');
getImage('large');
getText('small');
getText('large');
--------C---------
get('image','small');
get('image','large');
get('text','small');
get('text','large');
--------D---------
get(array('type'=>'image','size'=>'small'));
get(array('type'=>'image','size'=>'large'));
get(array('type'=>'text','size'=>'small'));
get(array('type'=>'text','size'=>'large'));
--------E---------
get('{"type":"image","size"=>"small"}');
get('{"type":"image","size"=>"large"}');
get('{"type":"text","size"=>"small"}');
get('{"type":"text","size"=>"large"}');
```

I could of included objects too, but I prefer to keep it simple for now.

The array in "D" is a php array to show the difference between example "E" that uses json.

You can probably see how the approach gradually shifts from one way of thinking to another, where function definitions turn to information exchange.
This does not mean that the "get" function is a master function that does everything, it might be a messenger function that calls other functions, its sole purpose might be to turn the app into a service.

### The questions are:

- What is this shift in coding style called? **(main question)**
- When is it best to use which?
- Where can I read more about this?

Clarification and comments/questions/answers in order to improve this question are welcome.

Comment: I'd use B for any sort of library and D/E for a web service. The others aren't very usable.

Comment: I would call it "abstraction." The question is when it makes sense to gather multiple kinds of functionality under one general-purpose function, and when to write single-purpose functions.

Comment: @Blender thanks for the input, much appretiated. With B I always have trouble deciding whether it is `getImage('small');` or `getSmall('image');`

Comment: C, D, and E perform the same function, but with different parameter types. If there's a name for this, I don't know it, but it seems like elementary programming evolution - writing methods that create output based on input parameters. Parameterization, maybe.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen When you write functions, look at the heirarchy you're creating. Would it be logical, within your heirarchy, to have a `getImage('small')`? Or would it be more logical to have a `getSmall('image')`? Small and large can be properties of an image, but "image" may not be a property of "small" and "large" (unless everything in your application works that way as well). Make your methods reflect your logic.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen for `getImage('small');` vs `getSmall('image');` -- one clearly indicates what sort of thing it's returning: an Image, while the other is returning something that's "Small", for some definition of Small, and you have no idea what kind(s) of Small stuff it could return.

Comment: @StephenP yes, I agree, the example I gave isn't the best because one word is an adjective while the other is a noun, it always makes more sense for adjectives to be the parameters. On the other hand, can there be verbNoun(Noun) function and parameter combinations?

Comment: @TimoHuovinen how about verbNoun(Subject, Adjective[s])? such as `convertImage(myImage, 'small')` or `convertImage(myImage, 'size=small', 'filter=bw')` etc.

Comment: @StephenP that sounds very reasonable, why didn't I think of that!

Comment: @StephenP I have thought a bit more about it, and it does seem to make sense to use Objects when there is a subject: `$subject->verbNoun($adjectives)`

Answer (score 2):

Naming function and passing values to functions has always been one of many topics of discussion. I would recommend you to look at what's commonly called "Clean Code". It contains theory for naming and constructing functions.
This is a good book to take a look at

[http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

and check YouTube for *Clean Code* and you will probably find a few good talks.

My thoughts is that you can do a *million* different ways when constructing functions. You could, in theory, besides your examples have a function called *Get* that takes a pointer to a function that returns the type of the thing to get. But the only thing this adds is complexity. What we want to achieve is basically self commenting code that is easy for other people to read and understand. For this, every function should follow set rules in regards to how it is named in accordance to what it performs, what it is allowed to change and return etc. This would make for much easier code for someone to get into.

This goes for classes to. Don't have some class that sets up a million things in it's constructor. If that is needed, then create functions to encapsulate the behavior and call these functions from the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

After you edited your question, I understood what you were trying to get at, here. I'm going to post this as an answer and risk the downvotes - I may edit it later on.

It seems as though you're trying to build a routing hierarchy through your functions; similar to a Web API or even the routing in an MVC application. You're building a tree, basically - at its root, you have `get` (which is the function name) and then you can pass parameters to that function which may or may not be dependent on each other.

Generalizing your API calls along logical bounds is indeed a different coding style, but I don't know if it works in your language of choice here.

**What is this shift in programming style called? (main question)**

I'm not sure, but I'll try to find it and re-edit this post.

**When is it best to use which?**

Your functions become more generic down the list. As such, I would use the more specific functions within specific scope (for instance, as a helper inside a class) and I would only expose the generic functions as part of a greater public interface.

**Where can I read more about this?**

I've got to do some reading myself - I understand the concept, but I don't know if I've seen a formal definition.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between C and D/E doesn't affect the logic of the function at all, just the way you call it. I use C for simpler functions, and switch to D and E under a few circumstances:

1. The list of arguments is long enough that calls and definitions are unwieldy. Passing an associative array lets you build up the arguments piece by piece.
2. The values you want to pass as arguments are coming to you already in an array or object, so it's more convenient to pass that than to unpack it first.
3. Your function has a lot of optional arguments. PHP doesn't support named arguments, so if you want to call a function that has 15 optional arguments and you're supplying 5, it's much easier to pass an array of arguments than to remember which of the 15 positions your 5 arguments go in, and write lots of `null`s between them.

For functions that take a small number of all- or mostly-required arguments, C can be useful because it makes it easier for other readers of your code to see the function's design and its requirements at a glance.